# Distributional Derivative of Heaviside Function times Log

Tags: analysis, distribution-theory

I was trying to calculate the distributional derivative of $H(x)\log(x)$, where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside Function.

$$
  \langle DH(x)\log(x), \phi(x) \rangle = -\langle H(x)\log(x), \phi^{\prime}(x) \rangle
$$

$$
= -\int_{-\infty}^\infty H(x)\log(x)\phi^{\prime}(x) \, dx
$$

$$
= -\int_0^\infty \log(x)\phi^{\prime}(x) \, dx
$$

$$
=-\left[ \log(x)\phi(x)\Big|^\infty_0 - \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x} \phi(x)\,dx \right]
$$

$$
=-\Big[\log(x)\phi(x)\Big|^\infty_0\Big] + \int_{-\infty}^\infty H(x) \frac{1}{x} \phi(x) \, dx
$$

Now I can write the second term as $\left\langle \frac{H(x)}{x}, \phi(x) \right\rangle$ but how to solve the first term. I am stuck at this step. Is there some other approach to solve this kind of integral? Or if my current working is correct up to this point, how do I proceed further?

Comment: This integration by parts doesn't seem useful, since neither of your two terms is a distribution by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost did it. You just have to be careful at $x=0.$ For example, you can use a limit:
$$
\langle \frac{d}{dx}(H(x) \ln(x)), \phi(x) \rangle
= - \langle H(x) \ln(x), \phi'(x) \rangle
= - \int_0^\infty \ln(x) \, \phi'(x) \, dx
\\
= - \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_\epsilon^\infty \ln(x) \, \phi'(x) \, dx
= - \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left( \left[ \ln(x) \, \phi(x) \right]_\epsilon^\infty - \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{1}{x} \, \phi(x) \, dx \right)
\\
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left( \ln(\epsilon) \, \phi(\epsilon) + \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{1}{x} \, \phi(x) \, dx \right).
$$

Comment: $ = \langle \frac1x 1_{x >0}, \phi(x)-\phi(0) 1_{x\in [0,1]} \rangle$

Comment: @reuns. The right hand side of that is not a $C^\infty_c$ function. That's a problem. Not too big, though, since the pairing is defined as an integral.